# rails get value using variable with self

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can we use variable as an attribute along with self ?
generally we do like self.profession but i want do like store 'profession' word in any string variable say 'x' and use it with self say self.x , but it is not working.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an attr_accessor in the model and then you can call it on any instance of that class

```
attr_accessor :x
```

Now `self.x = 'Profession'` will work properly.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

If 'profession' is a field in DB, then to get the value do this:

```
x = 'profession'
self.send(x)
```

Comment: Himesh, thanks for an answer. what i need to do here is to get a value of profession field from db.

Comment: Ok, so if profession is a field then what you can do is store 'profession' in a variable as `x = 'profession'` and get the value as `self.send(x)` . Hope this is what you are looking for!